# Eclipse plugin for DMN decision

Tags: drools, dmn

Do we have a DMN Editor /plugin /any other plugin which can be integrated with  Eclipse IDE to do DMN modelling   ?

Searched for it in eclipse marketplace DMN editor and couldn't find it . I am currently using Eclipse Oxygen   version for development purpose .

Answer (score 0):

Personally I just associate `.dmn` files with the [KIE DMN editor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.vscode-extension-dmn-editor) as this extension of VSCode which is quite lightweight solution even when not using directly VSCode as my main IDE; I have Eclipse to use the default OS system editor for managing `.dmn` files.

I use similar solution as well for other types of files, that is have Eclipse IDE use the default system editor, and that works very well for me. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks , I was primarily looking forward to avoid switching between multiple IDE/editor to do modelling and execution . As we have some  products used in our application due to which we are using Eclipse IDE only , hence i was looking forward for an eclipse plugin . even to manage decisions .

Comment: i would then expect if you can use a chromium or firefox based web-view in your eclipse ide, you could try to roll your own packaging of kie-tools there.